# ¿Por qué cuando actualizo la página se redirige a la primera ruta con react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

estás son mis rutas:

Este componente es Routes.js:

```
<Switch>
        <Redirect
          exact
          from='/login'
          to={'dashboards'}
        />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={DashboardsView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path='/dashboards'
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={Tutorial}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path='/tutoriales'
      />
</Switch>
```

En App.js tengo:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Routes />
</Router>
```

Son más, pero a efectos prácticos esto sirve.

Lo que pasa es que cuando estoy, por ejemplo, en `/tutoriales` y actualizo la página me redirige a `/dashboards` siempre.

Este es el método que me cambia de ruta:

```
const handleLinkTo = (to) => {
    history.push(to);
};
```

Al parámetro `to` le paso `'/dashboards'` o `'/tutoriales'` de acuerdo al botón que se presiona. Lo cual funciona, pero reitero que el problema está en que al actualizar el navegador siempre me lleva a la primera ruta.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un CodeSandBox para ver el código?. De esta manera ver si hay alguno de esos componentes que hagan ocasionar el error y detectarlo

Comment: Lo intentaré, en un rato lo publico y te aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el problema no esta en todo tu "setup" de las rutas, si no en como mandas a llamar esa function, yo tenia un problema parecido, y era porque en el link, le estaba mandando directamente llamar la funcion en el `onclick` del link, puede ser eso tu problema.

yo tenia algo como:

```
<a onClick={handleLinkTo} />
```

y se soluciono cuando lo cambie a:

```
<a onClick={(e) => handleLinkTo()} />
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Ya tuve ese problema y está solucionado de la misma forma, jeje. He estado ahondando en el código, y estoy seguro de que es el <Route exact path='/login'>
        <Redirect
          from='/login'
          to={{
            pathname: '/dashboards'
          }}
        />
      </Route> Cuando se actualiza la página vuelve a tomar las rutas, toma la primera y se redirige al login y luego el login a /dashboard... Supongo que el que hizo esto lo hizo mal.

Comment: Tambien eso me parecio raro, aunque hace rato que no use `react-router-dom` y no se si eso es valido, posiblemente tiene la logica de si ya esta logueado hacer el redirect no? lo digo porque tambien tenia ese error jejeje, pero ojala encuentres la solucion! ;)

Comment: Lo extraño es que en una versión anterior del código, el código es prácticamente el mismo pero no da ese problema...

Answer (score 0):

React-router-dom tiene un componente que se encarga de todo lo que deseas hacer  este hace la funcion de un anchor  y a la misma vez cuando le haces click hace el history.push si necesitas mas informacion aqui esta la [documentacion](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components)

todo se resumen a algo tan sencillo como

```
<Link to="[path]">[Texto del enlace]</Link>
```

de manera que para tus necesidades solo tendrias que remplazar los Link por los anchor que ya existen

```
<Link to="/dashboard">Ver Inicio</Link>
<Link to="/tutoriales">Tutoriales</Link>
```

PD: para importar el componente Link

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice un sandbox de tu estructura de ruteo con `BrowserRouter` en vez de `Router` y funciona perfecto, aca esta el codigo:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/login" to="/dashboards" />
        <Route path="/dashboards">
          <span>DASHBOARD</span>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tutoriales">
          <span>TUTORIALES</span>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Aca lo podes testear: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-spence-fmgqo?file=/src/App.js:0-477. Al menos no pasa lo que decias que cuando recargas /tutoriales te redirige a /dashboard.

Asi que yo probaria eso, cambiar Router por BrowserRouter, a menos que si o si necesites usar Router en tu aplicacion, pero tene en cuenta que es la interface a mas bajo nivel de ruteo de react router dom: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: Voy a probar como dices a ver si hay algún cambio, si me resulta te marco como respuesta y pongo recompensa para dartela.

Comment: No funcionó como dices, ya tenía <Router history={browserHistory}> que cumple el mismo papel (browserHistory es el hook del history). Supongo que el origen del error se encuentra en otra parte... Estaré editando la pregunta en algún momento para mostrar mayor profundidad de las rutas.

Comment: Es raro.. como ves en el sandbox, de esa forma deberia funcionar. Probaste usando BrowserRouter en vez de Router, verdad? Que tenes exactamente en el component: "RouteWithLayout"? Si queres pasame mas info del codigo del proyeto

Comment: Proba tmb cambiando en el Redirect:
<Redirect
          exact
          from='/login'
          to='/dashboards'
        />, fijate el to tiene {} sin necesidad. Tmb si podes decime q version de React y react-router-dom estas usando..

Comment: Después de actualizar corregí eso, pero funciona igual.

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en los `exact` y el redirect te manda a `/dashboards` terminas ahi

Comment: como deberia dejar el codigo?